# How can I print a php file (source) in the browser?

Tags: php, fopen, file-get-contents

How can I print a php file (source) in the browser without the php tags at the start and at the end?

So if my php file looks like this:

```
<?php
  if( true ){ 
    echo 'hello world';
  }
?>
```

And in another file I want to load that file and echo the if statement so from the line 2 to 4, but not loosing the tabbing.

I have tried: `fgets()` and `file_get_content()` functions, butI can only echo an non-tabbed data.

Is there a method for this problem? or I have to write code for tabbing the source?

Comment: You need to put tabs in the output that you echo if you want tabs in the output

Comment: Please include your attempts, no matter if they worked! Just show your effort and work

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I get all lines into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then I cut out the first and the last line with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). After this I simply loop through the array an print it)

```
<?php

    $lines = file("file.php");
    $lines = array_slice($lines, 1, count($lines)-2);

    foreach($lines as $line)
        echo str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $line) . "<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
  if( true ){  
    echo 'hello world'; 
  }
```